# Community promotion banners?

Tags: support, site-promotion

Are there any community promotion banners we can use now to promote Expatriates on the other sites?

For example, there's a [deprecated community ad](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1642/2495) on Travel.SE, which still shows the Area51 logo with commitment level. I'd like to replace it with something else, but I'm the person that, once tried to draw a horse, was conformed with "next time it'll look more like a tree"...

Comment: Yeah I tried drawing one once for Travel when ads appeared, it was deemed scary/creepy looking :(  It'd be great for someone with some design skills to produce something, and we can vote for it on travel.  Doesn't have to be complicated!

Comment: I'm honestly having trouble figuring out what to put in one .. some kind of alien identification card and a passport or something? Hard to visually capture 'expat' :)

Answer (score 4):

Gave it a shot, should be easy enough to muck around with the text in any sort of image editor if you want to work on copy.

> [image: Living Abroad? We Can Help]

I figured I'd grab two distinctive countries that people are likely to know and that aren't US-centric.

Per my understanding of Sztupy's comment:

> [image: Living Abroad? We Can Help]

Comment: What would happen if we'd replace the flags behind the two countries to signal the expat thingy?

Comment: @SztupY, You mean swap the orientation of the flag so the UK shape is on the Japan-side, and vice versa?